# How can I validate a Password during the creation of a new User in Apex?

Tags: apex, validation, user

I would know if there is an Apex method to validate a Password during the creation of a new User in Apex.

I found the method `Site.validatePassword(user, password, confirmpassword)` but it's available only during the self-registration for a community.

In my case, I'm exposing an Apex REST WS to create a new User and I would check if the password is correct or not in order to complete the process and create the User.

Comment: When you say *password is correct or not*, what are you referring to? How does your API receive the password? What do you want to check here?

Comment: You don't set the password until after user creation.

Comment: @JayantDas I'm exposing an Apex REST WS, I receive some parameters (firstname, lastname, password, email) and in my code I create the User. I'm implementing a validation on those parameters and for the password I want check if it fullfils my Password Policies (for example, Minimum password length)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, it's right. I create the user record and then I invoke the method System.setPassword(userID, newPassword) but I would check if the password fulfills my Password Policies otherwise I don't create the User and return an error.

Comment: I believe calling setPassword should fail if the value doesn't meet your policies. Have you tried it? What behavior do you observe? I personally haven't, it's just my assumption.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes, calling setPassword() fail and an Exception is thrown. In the worst case, I can use this approach (create the user, invoke setPassword and if it fails I will execute a rollback and return an error) but I prefer using a kind of validation method before the creation of the user. Thanks!

Comment: If you get password in your endpoint as a parameter, why not do some basic validation first with regex and/or something like passwordParam.length() < MIN_LENGHT and do Exception handling for the cases where this doesnt catch the validation?

Comment: @tugce You are right but I was looking for an out-of-the-box method to do that validation based on the Password Policies because, in this way when an Admin change it, I don't need to change my code to handle that.